# SELECT TOP 3 * FROM Customers order user_score by not working

Tags: mysql

I need to find top 3 scores and I am using top clause but it is not working and throwing illegal statement error I am using Mysql version 5.7.*.

What I am doing wrong. As per different example available I think my SQL syntax is correct. Is it a version issue?

Edit: Actual query

```
select top 3 * from customers order by user_score;
```

please have a look at following the link which demonstrates top clause
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-top-clause.htm

Comment: Can you share the full and exact query? The one from your question title is indeed not a valid MySQL query, but in at least two ways

Comment: seeing the actual SQL you're trying to run would help

Comment: `TOP` clause is not valid syntax for MySQL databases. The equivalent is `LIMIT` for MySQL.

Comment: @MokkyMiah The equivalent is ORDER BY... LIMIT...

Comment: Why people are downvoting this questions, isn't stack overflow for knowledge sharing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use limit instead of top for MySQL.

Try the following;

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    Customers
ORDER BY user_score
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `LIMIT` instead of `TOP`, because `TOP` isn't possible on a MySQL [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html):

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
ORDER BY user_score DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

> **demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qVLM7846ATFwYQwemzwiYC/1

---

The article on [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-top-clause.htm) also mentioned the `TOP` clause isn't available on all databases:

> **Note** − All the databases do not support the `TOP` clause. For example MySQL supports the `LIMIT` clause to fetch limited number of records while Oracle uses the `ROWNUM` command to fetch a limited number of records.

You can try the `TOP` clause on TSQL / MSSQL:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * 
FROM customers 
ORDER BY user_score DESC
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6ad9c/1/0

Comment: hi, @Sebastian Brosch, I can use limit but I am experimenting with the top clause and it is not working

Comment: @Thinker - `TOP` isn't available on a MySQL `SELECT` so you can't use it without error. Use `LIMIT` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use LIMIT and DESC in your sorting as you want the TOP 3 highest scores I presume, if you need the LOWEST use ASC.

`SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY user_score DESC LIMIT 3`

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY user_score ROWNUM <=3
```